# Can't change value in foreach from IEnumerable<Model>

Tags: c#, linq, model, ienumerable

How to change value of an object in `foreach` from `IEnumerable<Model>`.

Code:

```
public IEnumerable<Model> ListDaftarPjsp()
{
    IEnumerable<Model> list = from x in db.PJSPEvaluation
                              select new Model
                              {
                                  foo = x.Foo,
                                  bar = x.Bar               
                              };
    foreach (Model item in list) {
        item.condition = "example";
    }
    return list;
}

public class Model{
    public string foo{ get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
    public string condition{ get; set; }
}
```

I already create `Model`. Then I am looping result using foreach, then set it. But the Return  for `condition`still not changing? how to set condition inside foreach then return it for result

Comment: How fo you know, it does not change?

Comment: You cannot change the property list inside foreach loop, you must return it from LINQ: `from x in db.PJSPEvaluation select new Model {  foo = x.Foo, bar = x.Bar, condition = "example" };`.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` creates a view. It seems likely that you're reading from the database each time you loop through `list` in your example.

Comment: hover in return list in the last line. The condition not change @Backs

Comment: google "deferred execution": `list` is only a _query_, not the _answer_ to that query. Using `foreach` you execute that query. But then you return `list`, the original _query_, so anyone iterating that query again _executes_ it again, creating new `Model`s again...

Comment: I can't do like that because i have many condition insde foreach `if(item.foo == 1) { item.condition = a } else if(item.foo == 2) { item.condition = b }`  ..... and many again @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: You need materialize a query before updating a property: `var materializedList = list.ToList();` Then loop through `materializedList` and update `condition`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a query, not a collection.  While there is some sort of collection at the other end, the query itself *is not the collection*.  The nature of the collection you are targeting will determine whether or not you can modify the contents.

The general rule of thumb is that you can't expect an `IEnumerable<T>` to return the same list of objects twice, or even expect that you will be able to enumerate across it more than once - it is perfectly valid (if unusual) for an `IEnumerable<T>` to enumerate once only and refuse to enumerate a second or third time.

In this case what you have is actually a database query of type `IQueryable<Model>` that is cast to `IEnumerable<Model>`.  It's still an `IQueryable<Model>` which means that each time you enumerate across it you will get (probably) the same list of data but in completely new objects.  Changing one of the objects won't change all of the objects for the same source record, nor change the contents of the underlying record itself.

If you are trying to modify the returned objects without changing the underlying records (seems to be the case) then you need to materialize the query into a collection in memory.  There are a few ways to do this depending on what you're expecting to do with the returned data.

The simplest is to convert the query to an array using the `.ToArray()` extension method:

```
public Model[] ListDaftarPjsp()
{
    var query = from x in db.PJSPEvaluation
                select new Model
                {
                    foo = x.Foo,
                    bar = x.Bar               
                };

    var list = query.ToArray();

    foreach (Model item in list) 
    {
        item.condition = "example";
    }

    return list;
}
```

Now the records are in an array in memory and enumeration of that array can be done multiple times returning the same exact objects instead of fetching new copies of the data from the database every time.

Comment: "The nature of the collection you are targeting will determine whether or not you can modify the contents." Do you know on what it depends?

Comment: @BorisD Yes. Realized collections (arrays, lists, etc) of reference types will normally hand you references to the contained objects. If those objects are mutable you can update them. An enumeration that constructs objects on-the-fly from a stream, database, network connection or other source will likely give you newly-constructed objects that are then discarded, so changes aren't going to be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to create a list of `Model` using `LINQ`, then you are iterating the same for adding an additional property to each item. Then why don't you add the property at the time of creation of the list instead for an additional loop? Make things simple by try something like this:

```
from x in db.PJSPEvaluation
select new Model
{
   foo = x.Foo,
   bar = x.Bar,
   condition = GetCondition(x.Foo)              
};
```

Where the `GetCondition()` can be defined as :

```
private string GetCondition(int foo)
{
   if(item.foo == 1) 
   { 
      return "a";
   }
   else if(item.foo == 2) 
   { 
      return "b";
   }
   else
   {
      return "xx";    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already for this topic but there is more efficient way to do this. 
Just use List<> instead of Array[].

```
  public List<Model> ListDaftarPjsp()
    {
        List<Model> list = from x in db.PJSPEvaluation
                                  select new Model
                                  {
                                      foo = x.Foo,
                                      bar = x.Bar               
                                  };

        foreach (Model item in list) 
        {
            item.condition = "example";
        }
        return list;
    }

    public class Model{
        public string foo{ get; set; }
        public string bar { get; set; }
        public string condition{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I case you dont want to load items in memory with a `.ToArray` or `.ToList`

You can use `.Select` from Linq.

```
return myEnumeration.Select(item => {
   item.condition = "example";
   return item;
})
```